# Does the Min-max theorem hold in the case of primitive matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization

The original question was:

> Does the [Min-max theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem) hold in the case of nonsymmetric positive definite diagonalizable matrices?

As noted by [Omnomnomnom](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/81360/omnomnomnom) this is not true. Here is counterexample:

$$\pmatrix{ 3&1\\ 0&2 }$$

The matrix above is reducbile. What happens if one take a primitive matrice (irreducible aperiodic and non-negative)?

This is also false, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1691372/does-the-min-max-theorem-hold-in-the-case-of-primitive-matrices?noredirect=1#comment3453196_1691372) is another counterxample.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem#Counterexample_in_the_non-Hermitian_case

Comment: @5xum this matrix is not  positive definite.

Comment: Oh. Sorry, missed that part.

Comment: What do you mean by the "min-max theorem" when the matrix is asymmetric? The eigenvalues of the matrix are not necessarily real in the first place, even when the symmetric part of the matrix is positive definite.

Comment: As a counterexample, take the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{
2&1\\
0&2
}
$$

Comment: @user1551, by "positive definite" i mean "All its eigenvalues are positive"

Comment: @Omnomnomnom this is a good counterexample. Do you know what happens if we take a primitive matrice  (irreducible aperiodic and non-negative)? I think that in this case the maximal eigenvalue will correspond to the maximum of Rayleigh quotient. But the but the situation with the other eigenvalues is not so clear, because eigenvectors are not necessary ortogonal in the case of primitive matrices.

Comment: @SergeyKirgizov Actually, I noticed that my example wasn't diagonalizable. However,
$$
\pmatrix{3&1\\0&2}
$$
will definitely work

Comment: Also, the maximal eigenvalue will not generally correspond to the maximal Rayleigh quotient for primitive matrices.  It should be easy to find a counterexample...

Comment: Consider the fact that every matrix
$$
\pmatrix{2 & 1-t\\t&2}
$$
will have the same maximal Rayleigh quotient for any $t \in [0,1]$, but the eigenvalues will vary.  The maximal Rayleigh quotient is always an upper bound for the maximal eigenvalue.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom well... the last hope: Will it work if we take a row-stohastic matrix ?

Comment: No such luck, Sergey: if we take
$$
\pmatrix{1/2&1/2\\0&1}
$$
then we have a maximal Rayleigh quotient of $1.14 > 1$.  The same holds for
$$
\pmatrix{1/2&1/2\\t&1-t}
$$
when $t$ is a small enough positive number. Your trick **will work**, however, if you take a doubly stochastic matrix.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Omnomnomnom, I think I started to understand how it works: the maximum of Rayleigh quotient can be greater than $\lambda_{max}$, but Rayleigh quotient is (in the case of positive definite diagonalizable matrices) always maximised by the eigenvector that corresponds to $\lambda_{max}$. Could you confirm this?

Comment: @SergeyKirgizov that's not correct.  The eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda_{max}$ will always give you a Rayleigh quotient of $\lambda_{max}$.  Other vectors could potentially give you a higher Rayleigh quotient.  The theorem is specifically about symmetric matrices.

Comment: @SergeyKirgizov for more information on Rayleigh Quotients, you should look into the [numerical range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_range) of an operator.